# Cannot access S3 bucket from WildFly running in Docker

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, wildfly, octopus-deploy

I am trying to configure WildFly using the docker image jboss/wildfly:10.1.0.Final to run in domain mode. I am using docker for macos 8.06.1-ce using aufs storage.

I followed the instructions in this link https://octopus.com/blog/wildfly-s3-domain-discovery. It seems pretty simple, but I am getting the error:

WFLYHC0119: Cannot access S3 bucket 'wildfly-mysaga': WFLYHC0129: bucket 'wildfly-mysaga' could not be accessed (rsp=403 (Forbidden)). Maybe the bucket is owned by somebody else or the authentication failed.

But my access key, secret and bucket name are correct. I can use them to connect to s3 using AWS CLI.

What can I be doing wrong? The tutorial seems to run it in an EC2 instance, while my test is in docker. Maybe it is a certificate problem?

Comment: Is the IAM user which you use allowed to access the bucket? Like the first step in the example but than your bucketname + can you test it (ps your docker version is very old)

Answer (score 0):

I generated access keys from admin user and it worked.